# How to get clickable HREF tags in SVG image within Sharepoint Online Modern Pages

Tags: svg, sharepoint, click, href, sharepoint-online

I want clickable regions on SVG image displayed on Sharepoint Modern Pages. The image itself renders well, however links are not rendered at all.

The SVG file itself is embedded using Markdown. `![Click for Map](https://dummy.sharepoint.com/sites/LL/SiteAssets/Map.svg)`

```
<svg id="Layer_3" data-name="Layer 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="517.52" height="238.48" viewBox="0 0 517.52 238.48">
<a href="https://dummy.sharepoint.com/sites/LL" target="_blank"><path id="Dash1" d="M145.3,159.9l-5.11,15.84a12.13,12.13,0,0,1-10.54,8.36v0h92.42l-7.7-24.25Z"/></a>    
</svg>
```

The SVG file rendered in Chrome allows to click on the image and opens the link. The same file embedded in Sharepoint does not serve the link.

Comment: No. It is done via Markdown webpart. I could not find out how to use `<img>` on Modern Pages.

Comment: This is what I have found in _Inspect_. `<img alt="Click for Map" src="/sites/LL/SiteAssets/Map.svg" class="ms-Image-image is-loaded ms-Image-image--portrait image-229">`

Answer (score 1):

When you load SVG as an image, in this case via the `<img>` tag it is not interactive. This is a general rule and is not Sharepoint specific.

SVG used as an image has the same capabilities as raster images so that they can be used in the same situations without needing to specially consider their security and privacy implications.

Comment: Thank you. What embedding tags preserve interactivity?

Comment: <object> and <iframe>

Answer (score 0):

You can use image map to make clickable href in a img tag like this:

```
<img src="https://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png" usemap="#image-map">
<map name="image-map">
<area target="_blank" alt="bing" title="bing" href="https://www.bing.com" coords="37,35,363,104" shape="rect">
<area target="_blank" alt="Google" title="" href="https://www.google.com" coords="41,163,365,225" shape="rect">
<area target="_blank" alt="facebook" title="https://www.facebook.com" href="" coords="43,275,365,351" shape="rect">
</map>
```

For Modern Page, you could add the code snippet above via Modern Script Editor Web Part:

[Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Reference:

[How to Make image Map and use in SharePoint Online/2016/2013](https://www.sharepointsky.com/sharepoint-image-map/)

Comment: Thank you. We are again on adding Webpart from Github. And this is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Sorry if didn't provide you help.